# extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra) privateGPT

Tags: python-3.x, privategpt

I almost completed the installation og privategpt. It ingest my documents but when I  run privateGPT.py I get this error

```
extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
```

I tried to allow extra fields but could not find where to do it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.